# Looping through data in Javascript, combining new id's with old

Tags: javascript, jquery

Many times I'm having to loop through data and add the new to the old, but I can never seem to get it right.. Here's what I have now, basically trying to concatinate together the previous number from the new number, ultimately building a comma delimited string of numbers:

```
            function showItems(){
            if(prev_numbers == undefined){
                var prev_numbers = '';
            }else{
                prev_numbers = prev_numbers;    
            }

            numbers = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
            values = numbers +','+ prev_numbers;

                // Here is where some code would be that makes use of comma delimited numbers
                alert(values);  

            prev_numbers = values;

        }

        setInterval(showItems, 1000);
```

Comment: Basically, I keep getting prev_numbers either undefined or null...Does anyone know the proper way to handle this?

Comment: shouldn't you define `prev_numbers` outside of that `showItems`? It would help if you put together a demo, hard to see what you're doing to me.

Comment: prev_numbers will always be undefined because of function scope

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Array.join method?

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
values = numbers.join(',');
```

It's not clear where the numbers are coming from.  Perhaps post a little more code.

It seems like you're storing the history as a comma-delimited string, and adding new numbers to the beginning of the string as they come in.

Generally, it would make more sense to store the numbers as an array of numbers, then use join to build the string for display as needed.  You can prepend to the array using unshift:

```
numbers.unshift(Math.random() * 100);
```

Actually, I would recommend this even if the id's are strings.

Answer (score 0):

As meder said, you'd need to define `prev_numbers` outside `showItems`, or specify them as global by referencing them as a property of `window` (substitute `prev_numbers` by `window.prev_numbers`). That said, harpo's solution is a *lot* faster if you're splitting the string up again to access the separate numbers. We need to know a bit more about the context as well as your priority (speed? memory? code length? maintainability?).

By the way, this

```
        if(prev_numbers == undefined){
            var prev_numbers = '';
        }else{
            prev_numbers = prev_numbers;    
        }
```

is completely useless as far as I know. It might change the internal representation of `prev_numbers`, but with complicated things like JIT I'm not sure if that still holds. Your application doesn't seem to be interested in that anyway. As far as I can tell, this code can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to implement the [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoize) technique, i.e. you need a memoizer function.

Here's what Google came up with for a [JS memoize implementation](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/05/01/a-better-javascript-memoizer/).

Your doing it right, only that your neglecting that functions are implemented as a type in JS--it's a [first-class object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object), so these are completely valid statements:

```
function a() { };
a.foo = 'bar';
a.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // true
a.foo; // 'bar'

a = function { this.foo = 'bar' }
a.foo; // 'bar'
a['foo']; // 'bar', because objects are implemented as dictionaries
```

The only thing that you need to change is to set `prev_numbers` as a property of `showItems`:

```
function showItems() {
    // bool check for undefined object properties returns false
    if(!this.prev_numbers)
        this.prev_numbers = '';

    numbers = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    this.prev_numbers = numbers + ',' + this.prev_numbers;
}
```

As to your particular problem of always receiving `ReferenceError` in your code, I do not know the exact implementation details, but I have observed that accessing undefined globals will raise `ReferenceError` instead of simply returning `undefined`, as you'd expect. This is how to properly handle it:

```
 if (hasOwnProperty('prev_numbers') { ... }
 // equivalent to
 if(window.hasOwnProperty('prev_numbers') { ... }
```

Take a look at this:

```
baz; // ReferenceError
hasOwnProperty('baz'); // false
window.hasOwnProperty('baz') //false

baz = 'bar';
hasOwnProperty('baz'); // true
window.hasOwnProperty('baz) // true
```

An alternative to calling `hasOwnProperty` is:

```
foo; // ReferenceError
window.foo // undefined (no ReferenceError raised)

if (!window.foo) 'yay'; // 'yay'
if (window.foo == undefined) 'yay'; // 'yay'
```